# Open and close different divs through clicking menu

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, toggle, visibility

I’m having trouble with my JavaScript regarding turning visibility on and off between divs.

I have two columns; on the left is a menu and on the right is the space where I would like to display different divs. My intention is that:

1. When you click on a menu item, the relevant div appears on the right.
   (i.e. display: block)
2. When you click again on the same menu item, the
   relevant div closes (i.e. display: none)
3. When you click on a menu
   item, the relevant div opens, AND all other open divs close.

I've got it working nearly as I want it, though the current issue is that opening a div requires clicking twice. Also, as I am a complete novice at javascript, I imagine my code is MUCH more cumbersome than it needs to be. I’ve looked through similar examples but I can’t quite find the answer. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('hidden1')) {
      if (document.getElementById('hidden1').style.display == 'none') {
          document.getElementById('hidden1').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('hidden2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('hidden3').style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
  document.getElementById('hidden1').style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
}



function switchVisible2() {
  if (document.getElementById('hidden2')) {

      if (document.getElementById('hidden2').style.display == 'none') {
          document.getElementById('hidden2').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('hidden1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('hidden3').style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById('hidden2').style.display = 'none';

      }
  }
}


function switchVisible3() {
  if (document.getElementById('hidden3')) {

      if (document.getElementById('hidden3').style.display == 'none') {
          document.getElementById('hidden3').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('hidden1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('hidden2').style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById('hidden3').style.display = 'none';

      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftcolumn">

  <div class="leftmenu">

    <div class="subheader" onclick="switchVisible()">Content 1</div>

    <div class="subheader" onclick="switchVisible2()">Content 2</div>

    <div class="subheader" onclick="switchVisible3()">Content 3</div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="rightcolumn">

  <div id="hidden1">

    Content 1

  </div>

  <div id="hidden2">

    Content 2

  </div>

  <div id="hidden3">

    Content 3

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add similar classes to the elements to use them as reference. Then toggle one class in the matching clicked container:

```js
function switchVisible(el) {
  var classN = el.classList.value.split(' ')[1];
  if(classN == 'c1'){
    document.querySelector('.rightcolumn .c1').classList.toggle('hideContent');
  }
  else if(classN == 'c2'){
    document.querySelector('.rightcolumn .c2').classList.toggle('hideContent');
  }
  else if(classN == 'c3'){
    document.querySelector('.rightcolumn .c3').classList.toggle('hideContent');
  }
  
  var arrayOfElements = document.querySelectorAll('.rightcolumn div').forEach(function(div,i){
    if(!div.classList.value.includes(classN) && !div.classList.value.includes('hideContent')){
      div.classList.toggle('hideContent');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.rightcolumn div {
  font-size:20px;
  color: green;
}
.hideContent{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftcolumn">

  <div class="leftmenu">

    <div class="subheader c1" onclick="switchVisible(this)">Content 1</div>

    <div class="subheader c2" onclick="switchVisible(this)">Content 2</div>

    <div class="subheader c3" onclick="switchVisible(this)">Content 3</div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="rightcolumn">

  <div id="hidden1" class="c1 hideContent">Content 1</div>
  <div id="hidden2" class="c2 hideContent">Content 2</div>
  <div id="hidden3" class="c3 hideContent">Content 3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that! Makes sense to add reference classes.

Comment: Another quick question; if I wanted the divs to be hidden by default, would it be a case of changing hideContent to 'display:block' instead of 'none', and changing the CSS of the divs to they are 'display:none' on page load?

Comment: @jordanmiller, I have updated the answer to hide the content initially, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

I would instead of making it invisible just to offset it by a lot then set that value as a global variable then just set it to the CSS position attribute. Remember to make the position relative!